# Wait for multiple jobs to finish before start another one

Tags: jenkins

I want to start a jenkins job after two other projects are finished (Different order each deploy). I just saw the option to add a listener to only one project.

I tried to add a listener on 2 projects but I could just add one

Start Job 1 or 2 and if both are finished start Job 3. But Job 1 and 2 can start in different order depending on which is triggered first on the api

Comment: I am also looking for this but only one job. Do you have a link to the solution you mentioned with the listener for one job ?

Answer (score 0):

If you;re using Jenkins Pipeline ( doesn't meter if scripted or declarative ) you can create a simple logic with if/ else and parallel statements.

```
/* .. snip .. */
stage('run-parallel-branches') {
  steps {
    parallel(
      a: {
        echo "This is branch a"
      },
      b: {
        echo "This is branch b"
      }
   )
  }
}
/* .. snip .. */
```

src: https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/

and for control flow:

```
  if (false) {
     stage ('Stage 2') {
        sh 'echo Stage 2'
        }
  }
```

src: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#flow-control

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But in this case both jobs will be executed at the same time right? I need to trigger project 1 and project 2 and project 3 need to wait until both are triggered and finished. so something like if(job 1  && job2 are finished){ start job 3} I think that must be different, right?

Comment: if you use the "build" method then you can state for it to "wait" until job complition and play wit the logic there..
src: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/

look at the doc ( at the end ) at options for "wait" and also "propagate" might be useful for you...

Comment: ok thank you! will try that, I am quite new on this jenkins pipeline thing :)

Comment: what if those are actual jobs with their own pipelines? what is the solution for that? I have a case where we need a separate clean all job that can be run intraday or overnight so a clean build can start. it needs to wait until a job that kicks off 500 builds finishes.